# Does CruiseControl.NET have to access VisualSVN via HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, ccnet-config

I've recently got CruiseControl.NET setup to work with my VisualSVN server.  It works fine, and the TrunkURL uses the repository url that VisualSVN gave me, which starts with https.

I am however confused slightly because every example you see on the CruiseControl.NET website for subversion has the server using svn://.  I tried to use this vs. the https thinking that it may be faster but it will not work.

My question is this - does VisualSVN support this protocol or is it for standard Subversion (not VisualSVN)?  My VisualSVN server and CruiseControl.NET are on the same server so it seems pointless to use https if I'm working on the same box.  Also, it seems https is an unnecessary bottleneck if it's on the same server.

Am I missing something simple here or is this not possible?